# SQLite Get One result

Tags: sqlite

I know in MySQL, there is a LIMIT feature where you can limit your results.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'id' LIMIT 0,1`

Is there any way to do that in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same with SQLite. See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html